# Ability to run command line commands from intranet site

Tags: javascript, security, internet-explorer

My company has an intranet site where we store customer information.  We have a second fat client application that stores additional information about our customers.  This fat client has a method to run command line commands to open the application and immediately browse to a particular customer record.  We are looking for a way to add a hyperlink or button to customer page on our intranet site that will automatically open the fat client application and browse to the matching customer's information (using the fat clients command line commands).

I know that modern browsers go to great lengths to prevent what I'm trying to do because of security restrictions, but I wanted to make sure it's 100% impossible before saying so to my team.  This will only be used by internal employees and we have full control over the security configuration of their browser.  We use IE for this particular intranet site.

If you have any ideas on how this can be done, and have additional information on the security implications of your solution I'd be interested in that information as well.

Comment: Add a custom protocol to all the machines: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no javascript required for this. Use a custom protocol scheme for the arguments, like `myfatclient:cmdargs` which you can use as the `href` of a button or link.

See [Registering an Application to a URI Scheme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at MSDN for how to open your fat client with that scheme.

The security considerations are quite low, as long as the command line does not allow to change the data but only to display it. Your employees will need to be watch out for phishing attacks, or some kind of cross-application-request-forgery which might be enabled when installing the handler. See also the security section of the linked page.

Comment: If I understand the security implications correctly, I should assume that a malicious user could send any parameter to the application so I will want to make sure that there are no parameters that could cause harmful behavior.  Is it possible for a malicious user to run any command other than the application that has been registered (with some combination of parameters)?

Comment: No, only the registered applications can be started. Whether a malicious "user" (any website) can activate the link on its own should depend on your browser security settings; if those are implemented well the employee who uses the browser would need to explicitly click the link (but still he might be tricked into doing that). Not allowing harmful parameters is definitely a good idea.